# load swf to background of sprite

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

i have saved my background as a swf file.

```
    [Embed(source="Back.swf")]
    private var SomeClass:Class;
```

Now inside the main class i added

```
addChild(SomeClass);
```

But i get this red problem :- Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type Class to an unrelated type flash.display:DisplayObject.  Test.as /Test/src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using the `addChild` method, you need to parse there a `DisplayObject` type. in this case your `SomeClass` is `Class` type.

try:

```
addChild ( new SomeClass () );
```

or

```
addChild ( new SomeClass () as MovieClip );
```

Comment: How can i first assign it to a variable ? I need to do it because i need to do change its width and height.

Comment: `var item:MovieClip = new SomeClass () as MovieClip;`